# Bat file on top of all windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for a command that will always keep the command prompt on top of all other windows so that my batch script will always be visible, no matter how many other windows are opened.

I have not been able to find any information on this anywhere online, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the "it" you want to have always-on-top? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: There is no such command.

Comment: @KenWhite it would be possible to *write* such a command, but I don't see any indication that that's what is being asked here.

Comment: @Mark: The poster is asking for a "command line" that can be included in a bat file to make the command window always on top. AFAIK, there is no existing command available from a command prompt that will do so. If there is, it certainly isn't documented by MS AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can offer is `appActivate` method from `WScript.Shell`. this will require jscript or vbscript.Here's an example with batch/jscript hybrid.You can test if it works.You can put the appActivate in loop to be sure the will window will get on top:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off 
        rem title is needed so the appActivate to be able to recognize the current shell
        title ###

        rem waiting so we'll have time to switch the windows
        ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul 2>nul

        rem the jscript part with the appActivate is called
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %*

        rem checking the result
        echo are we on top?
        pause

        exit /b %errorlevel% 
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 

var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Echo(sh.AppActivate("###"));
```